# Fill in a list of matrices in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I want to give a constant columns value to every matrices in a list of matrices. Here is the list of matrices.

```
list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod <- lapply(1:4, function(i)
                             matrix(sample(1:50, 4*10, replace=TRUE),
                                 ncol=4, dimnames=list(NULL, LETTERS[1:4])))
```

Here is one matrix's example.

```
[[1]]
       A  B  C  D
 [1,] 15 31  5 16
 [2,] 12 19 28 12
 [3,] 36 34 37 19
 [4,] 26 34  7  8
 [5,] 34 17 12 47
 [6,] 47 46 35 11
 [7,] 14 10  4 37
 [8,] 39  3 30 32
 [9,] 41 26 32 35
[10,] 13  7  3 49
```

I want the column D in each matrices to get the values `Modis500_2000` instead of the numbers.

I also want the column C to be equal to AB. For instance, in the matrix example above, I want the column C in the row one to get the value 1531 instead of 5.

Comment: I do remember this code :-)

Comment: Indeed, it was yours ;). But one `map` function erase the effect of the previous one unless I give a new name to the new list of matrices.

Comment: Not tested, but have you tried all this in one step. ie. `columnsToTransfer <- c(ColumnsToTransfer1, ColumnsToTransfer2, ColumnsToTransfer)` and then use `columnsToTransfer`

Comment: It is not working either.

Comment: @akrun. I updated my question for something that I did not manage to do as well (see last part of the question). Can you help me with that?

Comment: Please consider showing some example dataset.

Comment: I think I have already mentioned about the difficulty in using this type of data considering there are better approaches to show the data `dput` or even creating an example data as I showed in the earlier post.

Comment: Updated with your list of matrix example.

Comment: `Map(function(x,y) {x[,"D"] <- y;x }, list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod, "Modis500_2000")`. Here, I am assuming that `Modis500_200` is a string

Comment: Great. Thanks. I have a last question for you. See updated question.

Comment: I posted it as answer.

Comment: I should have mentioned that it would be better to have mixed classes in data.frame.  Also, I suggested `paste0(x[,"A"], x[,"B"])` based on how you showed the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your previous question ([Add new columns to every matrices in a list of matrices in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482214/add-new-columns-to-every-matrices-in-a-list-of-matrices-in-r)) and I would highly suggest that you switch to using data.frames instead of matrices. It is in my opinion a better data structure for your type of work. Then you can use a function like `transform` to add/modify columns, in a rather simple and intuitive way:

```
list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod <- lapply(list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod,
                                   transform,
                                   C = A * B,
                                   D = Modis500_2000,
                                   E = A + B)
```

This will modify two columns (`C` and `D`) and add one (`E`).

If you ever need to convert your data back to matrices, then you can do:

```
list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod <- lapply(list_matrix_Tanzania_Mod,
                                   data.matrix)
```